# Data type conversion

Tags: java

```
 Float f;
 Long l;
 Char ch;
 Byte b;
 l=f;
 ch=b;
```

Why is this code give error?? (as i know Char and long are large range of types than each data types)

Comment: Your question is incoherent. `Long l = 3.14;` What should that do?

Comment: `java` and `javascript` are diferent languages. Which one is it?

Comment: Sorry guys..its about only java

Comment: nope brother i think that you know about conversion of data..under that topic we concern about ranges of data type..so small range of data type could conversion to large range of data type..so when i go to my quection char long data type has 64 bits and  float has 32 bit..but couldnt conver float to long..it gives error...i asked that what is error of it??

Comment: It gives error because `f` and `b` are un-assigned. They have no value. --- It gives error because `Float` *object* is not assignment compatible with `Long` *object*. Even if you used *primitive values*, you cannot assign `float` to `long` without casting, because that is a *[Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)*. You also cannot assign `Long` *object* to `Float` *object*, but you can assign `long` to `float` *([Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2))*.

Comment: @Andreas k thank you
But why we can not assing byte to char (widening primitive conversion not support)

Comment: @GihanWijesuriya Because `char` is unsigned, so any negative `byte` values would be lost, i.e. the number-space of `byte` is not a subset of the number-space of `char`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do You mean?

You have to cast f to long and b to char and also initialize them.

> l = (long) f;
>   ch = (char) b;

```
//----
float f = 3.14f;
long l ;
char ch;
byte b = 38;
l= (long) f;
ch= (char) b;
```

Check examples:

```
int first = 3:
int second = 2;
double result = first / second;  // the result is 1 because first and second are integers

first = 3;
second = 2;
double result1 = (double)first / second;  // result is: 1.5

double result2 = first / (double)second;  // result is: 1.5

double result3 = (double)(first / second);  // result is: 1
```